# How do I close menu on click and when the user clicks away?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, click, stoppropagation

I have the following code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".clicker_class").click(function () {
            $('.show_menu_users').show();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

$('.clicker_class').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I am new to JQuery and a bit puzzled.  I was easily able to use the show function but I need to use the close or hide function to close the menu when the user clicks on .clicker_class again and when the user clicks away at something else. I tried using the e.stopPropogation(); but didn't work.  How do I do that given my above code?

Update:

```
I got it to close if a user clicks elsewhere using this:

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".clicker_class");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
         $(".show_menu_users").hide();
    }
});
```

**Question:**

Now I just need the menu to close when the user clicks on .clicker_class.  How can i do that now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED to close menu if clicked outside of `clicker_class` elements.

You can track the state of the `show_menu_users` using a boolean. When you click on the `clicker_class` elements, toggle the menu and update the boolean. When you click elsewhere in teh document, close the menu.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var isShowing = false;

        var toggleMenu = function() {
            isShowing = !isShowing; //change boolean to reflect state change
            $('.show_menu_users').toggle(isShowing); //show or hide element
        }

        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            if($(e.target).is('.clicker_class') || $(".clicker_class").has(e.target).length !== 0) {
                toggleMenu();
            } else {
                isShowing = false;
                $('.show_menu_users').hide();  
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[**Working example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/84w5T/1)

Comment: Thanks.  But how do I merge your code with my above update about closing the menu above when user clicks elsewhere?

Comment: @starbucks I updated my answer and jsFiddle, so now it should close the menu when you click away from `clicker_class`.

Answer (score 4):

Cfs's solution works but there is an easier way to do that, without basing yourself on a global variable (which is better to avoid).

The ".toggle()" function (without parameters) of jQuery hide your element if it is visible and show it if it isn't. Then you just have to launch $( ".show_menu_users" ).toggle() when you click on the button and hide the menu when you click on the document. The problem is that clicking on any elements will close the menu, to prevent it you just have to stop the event propagation by using "event.stopPropagation()"

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $( ".clicker_class" ).on( "click", function ( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 

       $( ".show_menu_users" ).toggle(); 
    });

    $( document ).on( "click", function () {
        $( ".show_menu_users" ).hide(); 
    }); 

    $( ".show_menu_users" ).on( "click", function ( event ) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
    }); 
});
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/4CEpW/)

Answer (score 2):

See if its fit your needs:

```
$(function(){
    //we set a tabindex attribute in case of this element doesn't support natively focus
    //outline just for styling
    $(".clicker_class").prop('tabindex',-1).css({outline:0});
});

$(".clicker_class").click(function () {
     $('.show_menu_users').toggle();
}).on('focusout',function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work on mine.  NOt sure if I did something wrong on my end.. let me retry.

Comment: i didn't test it, maybe something is missing

Answer (score 0):

I use this method, which I think is a cleaner answer.

Add to your html page just after/before the opening/closing body tag:

```
<div class="main-mask"></div>
```

Then in your js file:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  $(".sidenav-toggle").on( "click", function() {
      $("#sidenav").toggleClass("sidenav--open");
      $(".main-mask").toggleClass("main-mask-visible");
  });

  $(".main-mask").on( "click", function() {
      $("#sidenav").toggleClass("sidenav--open");
      $(".main-mask").toggleClass("main-mask-visible");
  });

})();
```

In your css:

```
.main-mask {
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

This way, your mask acts as the click away. You can bind/unbind events and use the `.main-mask` class with other elements. The downside is that it needs to be added to the page. You could use css `body:after {content:''}` to remove that dependency.