# Change max height element after it being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writting a dropdown menu and I wanted to have the dropdown being controlled by javascript.

My dropdown has the sub menu hidden of sight `max-height: 0px;` and when the correspondent anchor tag is clicked, I change its `max-height` parameter to 400px, using the following function:

```
function drop_down(name) {
    document.getElementById(name).style.maxHeight = "400px";
}
```

So far so good. The problem is that the element's `max-height`, stays at 400px and the sub menu does not hide. So I thought that I should target the click of the mouse and when this happens check if there is any element with 400px and change it back to 0.

```
$('html').click(function() {
   var max_h = document.getElementsByClassName("nav_content");
   var i;

   for(i = 0 ; i < max_h.length ; i++)
   {
        if(max_h[i].style.maxHeight == "400px")
        {
            max_h[i].style.maxHeight = "0px";       
        }
    }
});
```

What happens is that this function tracks every click, even the one used to display the sub menu. So my question is: is there a way to only activate the second function after I clicked my sub-menu? Because I always want the click that comes after the menu is displayed to close the sub menu.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="nav_container">
        <nav class="nav_main">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="../majo.png" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav" id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="user_menu.php" class="nav_item">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_item" onclick="drop_down('nav_consul')">Consultas</a>
                    <div id="nav_consul" class="nav_content">
                        <div class="nav_sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/inf_dia_dia">Informação Dia a Dia</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/tot_men">Totais Mensais</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/cur_tar">Tarifário Atual da Rede</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/dat_esp">Data específica</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/sys_act">Atividade do Sistema</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="consul/coimas">Coimas</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_item" onclick="drop_down('nav_simul')">Simulações</a>
                    <div id="nav_simul" class="nav_content">
                        <div class="nav_sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="simul/add_simple_tar">Criar tarifa Simples</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="simul/add_complex_tar">Criar tarifa Complexa</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="simul/simular">Simular com Nova Tarifa</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_item" onclick="drop_down('nav_prefs')">Preferências</a>
                    <div id="nav_prefs" class="nav_content">
                        <div class="nav_sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="prefs/list_access">Lista de acessos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="prefs/alt_pass">Alterar Password</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="prefs/alt_dados_conta">Alterar Dados de Conta</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="../log_out.php" class="nav_item">Log Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="content_main">

    </div>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="../js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/user_menu.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/user_nav.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/user_clear_sub_menu.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could display the sub-menu items on hover instead of on click. This will prevent any confusion.

Comment: I don't want to use hover, because I want to test this in mobile devices as well.

Comment: In mobile device you can have hover effect only after touch

Comment: use `preventDefault()` with your drop down.

Comment: Why don't you add a class on opening and target the class when you need to set `max-height:0`?

Comment: Could you show your markup please?

Comment: Hover works in mobile devices as well - a click is treated as a hover, so it should work.

Comment: You need to show you're the HTML you are using in order to workout what you need.  Currently your click handler for closing the menu is on `html` which will look for clicks anywhere on the page.  Additionally, you should consider using classes rather than setting the attributes inline.

Comment: I'm adding the html part now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an easy solution:

Create the following CSS-Styles:

```
.nav_content.visible {
    max-height: 400px;
}
.nav_content.invisible {
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

Set the overflow property for your `nav_content` to hidden:

```
.nav_content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now add the class `invisible` to your submenus, if you want them to be invisible by default (you can do this manually in the markup or by js code):

Manually e.g.:

```
<div id="nav_prefs" class="nav_content invisible">
```

or by code (after the elements have been loaded):

```
$(".nav_content").addClass("invisible);
```

Now, if you just need to adjust your `drop_down` function to toggle the element's `invisible`/`visible` class:

```
function drop_down(dropdownID){
    $('#'+dropdownID).toggleClass("visible invisible");
}
```

UPDATE: To make all visible submenus disappear when clicked elsewhere use this piece of code, when the window is loaded:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.nav_item') && !$(".nav_item").has(e.target).length !== 0) {
        $('.nav_content.visible').toggleClass("visible invisible");
    }
});
```

If you only want to have one submenu visible at a time, you can use this version of your `drop_down` function:

```
function drop_down(dropdownID) {
    $('.nav_content.visible').toggleClass("visible invisible");
    $('#' + dropdownID).toggleClass("visible invisible");
}
```

A working fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/974rn4pu/2/)

EDIT: Since you used `jQuery` in your original code, I assumed the answer can use `jQuery` too

Comment: Your answer has a nice approach (a simple one, that a noob like me can follow), however it does not hide when anywhere else is clicked. To re-hide the sub menu you need to re-click it.

Comment: @Comum okay sorry I misunderstood you there. I will change my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a click handler on your document, then check the target of the click. If the target of the click has a certain class, use the menu behavior. If not, or if it's a sub-menu, close the menu.

Here's a question with multiple examples:

[How do I close menu on click and when the user clicks away?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822131/how-do-i-close-menu-on-click-and-when-the-user-clicks-away)

Also, I'd recommend not using max-height to hide and show. Since you're using jquery already, you could just use hide() and show().

One more thing: since you're using jquery already, you don't need to use these calls: `document.getElementById(name)`. You can do a `$("#yourId")` or for `document.getElementsByClassName("nav_content");` you can use `$(".your-class")`

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can use **[jQuery.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** method to exclude the dropdown menu from your jQuery selection, here's what you need :

```
$('html').not(document.getElementsByClassName("nav_container")[0]).click(function() {
//As you can pass an element to it
```

You can also use the `:not` in your first selector like this:

```
 $('html:not(div.nav_container))
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you attached click event to entire document. I think you need to change only `$('html').click(function() {` to something like `$('sub-menu-selector').click(function() {` to

> only activate the second function after I clicked my sub-menu

Aside to that, since it's only piece of jQuery and if you're not using it elsewhere, I would replace this with `addEventListener` and `attachEvent`, but maybe that's just me :)